# Bank project, Array problem in how storing account within array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

this is a sample of my code 
My problem is in how create an account one by one without Enter the 50 accounts at one time, for example if i want just to save 10 accounts and be sure that the accounts are not written above each other, and thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
                   String Administrator = "Amro" ;
                   String Password = "1234567";
    System.out.println("login the bank system ");
    System.out.println("1- login as Administrator ");
    System.out.println("2- login as a user ");
    System.out.println("3- Exit ");
    int x = keyboard.nextInt() ;
    switch(x){
        case 1 :               
            System.out.println("Enter username :");
            String username = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Password :");
            String password = keyboard.next();
            if(username.equals(Administrator) && password.equals(Password)){
             System.out.println("Enter type of operation :");
                }else{ System.out.println("ERORR!!!!");
                   System.exit(0);}               
            boolean isRunning = true;
            while(isRunning){
             System.out.println("1- Create a new account");
              System.out.println("2- Deposit an amount in the account");
               System.out.println("3- Withdraw an amount in the account");
                System.out.println("4- Modify the customer data");
                 System.out.println("5- Delete the bank account");
                  System.out.println("6- Search for a bank account");
                   System.out.println("7- View all bank account");
                    System.out.println("8- Go back");
                    int y = keyboard.nextInt();
                    switch(y){
                        case 1:
                        String Info [][] = new String [50][5];
                           System.out.println("*Create a new account*");
                           for(int i=0;i<+Info.length;i++ ){
                                for(int j=0;j<1;j++){
                            System.out.println("Customer ID number :");
                           Info [i][j] = keyboard.next();
                           System.out.println("Customer Name :");
                           Info [i][j+1] = keyboard.next();
                           System.out.println("Customer password :");
                           Info [i][j+2] = keyboard.next();
                           System.out.println("Customer's phone number :");
                           Info [i][j+3] = keyboard.next();
                                }
                           }
  //                   for(int i=0;i<Info.length;i++ ){
  //                   for(int j=0;j<1;j++){
  //                  System.out.println(Info [i][j]);  
  //                   System.out.println(Info [i][j+1]);
  //                   System.out.println(Info [i][j+2]);
  //                   System.out.println(Info [i][j+3]);
  //                                      }
                   //                }
                   }

                  }
                  }
              }
          }
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: What is the point of `for(int j=0;j<1;j++)`?

Comment: i think nothing i delete it

Answer (score 0):

To change the number of account entries here, you would update the following existing line:

```
String Info [][] = new String [50][5];
```

For example, if you wanted to enter 10 accounts, you would change it to:

```
String Info [][] = new String [10][5];
```

If you wanted to have the user enter how many accounts they planned to enter, you could use:

```
int z = keyboard.nextInt();
String Info [][] = new String [z][5];
```

Comment: thanks ! you answer the first side of my Question ,  i understood you but the problem is that when i try to create 2 account once for example the second one will be written over the first one how to solve this

Comment: For the first 'set' of accounts, you are saving it to the Info array.  The first account is saved in Info[0][], the second account is saved in Info[1][] and so on.  After that first 'set', if the user chooses to enter a second set of data, you'd need to either offload the existing Info array to permanent storage (like a database or text file), or increase the size of the Info array and make sure you start the iterator (i) after the previously stored data's highest index plus 1, or dynamically create a new array and add it to a List of arrays with more account data.